# Logit Price-Response Function and probability

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

Looking at the logit price-response function taken from [here](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02735/RMlecture04.pdf).

[image]

I take it that the output would be a probability, if C = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document you mentionned, you can read that :

**Recall, d(p) is the number of customers willing to pay at least p for the product**

So it should not be a probabilty ..

Comment: so maybe I could use the standard logistic function as in logistic regression?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: basically I want it to be a probability ... x axis corresponds to the price and y to the probability (probability = 1 at price 0)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you .. what do you call a probability ?

Comment: a value between 0 and 1 indicating purchase probability given price???

Comment: but d(p) represent the demand as a function of price .. in what sense would you like d(p) to be a probabilty ? Why are you wanting to see d(p) as a probabilty ? I think I'm unable to understand your issue beacause I don't know your goal ..

Comment: Can I please delete - i.e. can you delete your answer please?

Comment: I'm able to do it .. of course .. but can you explain me why ?

Comment: I was talking nonsense and so is my question (-: (sorry had a cold and struggled a bit this week)